# Why does the angular average of this divergence give rise to a factor 1/3?

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

In going from eq.(6.13) to (6.14) in http://www.nano.northwestern.edu/intranet/pubdocs/quasiclassical.pdf it is assumed that
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{d\Omega_{\vec{p}}}{4\pi}\,(\hat{p}\cdot\hat{p})\nabla_{\vec{r}}\cdot\vec{f}=\dfrac{1}{3}\nabla_{\vec{r}}\cdot\vec{f},$$
where
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{d\Omega_{\vec{p}}}{4\pi}\,\vec{g}=\langle\vec{g}\rangle$$
is the angular average of the function $\vec{g}$, and $\hat{p}$ is a vector with unit length pointing in the direction of the momentum. (The notation in the article is a bit misleading, from eq.(6.1) it can be seen that $\hat{g}_p$ is a vector, hence the paraphrasing here.)

**Question:** Where does this factor $1/3$ come from? The angular average of a scalar should be the scalar itself, and the dot product of a unit vector with itself should be one.

---

What has come up so far, is that
$$\dfrac{1}{4\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\phi\,d\phi\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\sin\theta\sin^2\theta\,d\theta=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int_0^\pi 3\sin\theta-\sin(3\theta)\,d\theta=\dfrac{1}{3},$$
which means that
$$\langle\hat{p}_x^2\rangle=\langle \cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta\rangle=\dfrac{1}{3},$$
as we would expect since $\langle\hat{p}_x^2+\hat{p}_y^2+\hat{p}_z^2\rangle=1$. This means that
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{d\Omega_{\vec{p}}}{4\pi}\left(\hat{p}_x^2\partial_x\hat{x}+\hat{p}_y^2\partial_y\hat{y}+\hat{p}_z^2\partial_z\hat{z}\right)\cdot\vec{f}=\dfrac{1}{3}\nabla_{\vec{r}}\cdot\vec{f},$$
which suggests that for the first line to be true we should have
$$\left(\hat{p}_x^2+\hat{p}_y^2+\hat{p}_z^2\right)\left(\partial_x\hat{x}+\partial_y\hat{y}+\partial_z\hat{z}\right)\cdot\vec{f}=\left(\hat{p}_x^2\partial_x\hat{x}+\hat{p}_y^2\partial_y\hat{y}+\hat{p}_z^2\partial_z\hat{z}\right)\cdot\vec{f}.$$
This is only true if the crossterms with different index ($\hat{p}_x^2\partial_yf_y$, $\hat{p}_x^2\partial_zf_z$ etc) are either zero or cancel each other out. If this line of reasoning is correct, the question would become: *Why do these crossterms drop out*?

---

**Update:** The first of the cited equations in the article appears to be wrong.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the unit ball volume $\frac{4\pi}{3}$?

Comment: @A.G. The factor $\frac{1}{3}$ in $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ comes from the radial part of the volume integral, which isn't present in the angular average (hence the factor of just $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ in front to normalize).

Comment: I did not look into details, just a guess: if $d\Omega$ is the volume element  of $3D$ unit ball (is it?) then $\int d\Omega=\frac{4\pi}{3}$. After canceling $4\pi$ it is $\frac13$ left. And $p\cdot p=|p|^2=1$.

Comment: @A.G. Jupz, you're absolutely right if $d\Omega$ were the volume element :). However, in this case $d\Omega$ is a solid angle element (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle).

Comment: I am confused with the notations. Is $(\hat p\cdot \hat p)$ the scalar product? Shouldn't it be one then for unit vectors? What I know is that $\frac13$ appears in the following averaging for any vector $A$: $$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\hat p(\hat p\cdot A)\,d\Omega=\frac13A$$.

Comment: @A.G. Yeah, I got the same confusion about the $\hat{p}\cdot\hat{p}$ having to be one. What I do know is that $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})(\vec{c}\cdot{d})\neq(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{d})(\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c} )$, which means that we can't move the dot product from between the $\hat{p}\cdot\hat{p}$ to the $\nabla$. Just to be sure, your averaging yields $1/3$ because you get a $\cos^2\theta$ term, one cosine for the $\hat{p}$ and another cosine for the $\hat{p}\cdot\vec{A}$, right?

Comment: Due to rotational symmetry, assume WLOG that $A=(0,0,1)$. The last coordinate gives as you say $\cos^2\theta$ that integrates to $1/3$. Other two components give zero integral.